# MVC 4 Reporting with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, reporting-services, dataset

I'm using MVC4 and Entity Framework in order to develop an intranet web app and I have to create reports which can be dowloaded by the users. In fact, I have 2 report templates (.rdlc files). One of them is a generic template which will be copied and modified for the next templates. That's what I did with my "PersonReport" template : copied and modified from the generic.

My problem is that with the genereic template (and the code below), everything's fine. However, when I'm using my personalized template, it doest not work. I tried to debug my code and I found where is the issue (when I'm using the .Render() to specifiy the format). There is my error message :

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
```

Here is my action :

```
public ActionResult PersonReport()
{

    ReportViewer personReportViewer = new ReportViewer();

    //Parameters

    ReportParameter[] reportParameters = new ReportParameter[3];
    reportParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("Title", "Test", true);
    reportParameters[1] = new ReportParameter("Address", "Avenue de Tervuren,  268", true);
    reportParameters[2] = new ReportParameter("PostalCode", "B-1150 Brussels", true);

    //Report Template

    personReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    personReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("..") + "\\Reporting\\Templates\\" + "AllPersonsReport.rdlc";

    //Source

    DataSet ds = BuSIMaterial.Utils.Services.ExecuteStoredProcedure(db, "GetAllPersons", null);

    ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource("personDataSource", ds.Tables[0]);
    personReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    personReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);

    //Report type

    personReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
    byte[] byteArray = personReportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF"); //Here's the failure

    //Downloading

    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; Filename=\"" + DateTime.Now + "_Title_.pdf" + "\"");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "Binary");
    Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])byteArray);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And my method to create a DataSet from a simple select * stored procedure :

```
public static DataSet ExecuteStoredProcedure(ObjectContext db,
                                     string storedProcedureName,
                                     IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters)
{
    var connectionString =
        ((EntityConnection)db.Connection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString;

    var ds = new DataSet();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }
            }

            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
    }

    return ds;
}
```

**UPDATE** : I wanted to check if my DataSet was filled and it isn't. Could it be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean your dataset is the problem? Also for code neatness reasons look at FileResult instead of messing with response headers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In fact I wasn't right, the DataSet is not the problem. It's while I call the .Render() menthod that all goes wrong.

Comment: you should try to use another version or [Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251837(v=vs.100).aspx), with more parameter to get more informations on the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try adding more parameters to your Render() overload:

```
    private Warning[] warnings;
    private string[] streams;
    private string mimeType;
    private string encoding;
    private string extension;

    byte[] byteArray = personReportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streams, out warnings);
```